# Unable to install Tensorflow with CUDA and Cudnn on DGX-2 Tesla

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run my tf code on a Tesla GPU. But when I create a pod on the **`nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:19.01-py3_v3`** image. However i get the following stack trace while importing tensorflow. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/srivastava6/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/srivastava6/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/srivastava6/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like problem with CUDA, what version do you of CUDA do you have? And if it is 10.1 than you to downgrade or compile tensorflow yourself.

Comment: CUDA version: 10.1 
The issue is that the code we are using requires TF 1.3/1.4/1.5 which are not tensorflow-gpu compatible, hence the error